# What is the most memory/storage efficient encoding scheme for fixed length boolean arrays?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I've got 3mil boolean numpy ndarrays each of length 773 currently stored in a pandas dataframe. When they're being used, they need to be in the form of a fixed lenght array, but when in memory and storage I can use whatever encoding scheme is smallest.

As of right now I'm just saving off the arrays directly into the dataframe, but I'm unsure if I should pack the booleans into a handful of integers and save them off or if there's a way to write arbitrary binary data into a dataframe and unpack that. In short, what's the smallest/easiest to use format for saving off these arrays?

Comment: The shortest (i.e. most memory efficient) is probably `bytes` or `bytearray`.  These are primitive.  There isn't a primitive "array of bits".  The easiest ... would be to find some 3rd-party class that provides a nice "array of bits" API, but that most likely won't be the most memory efficient way.  (Conflicting requirements ...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's take a smaller [minimal workable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (yeah, they help to attract more help!):

```
>>> X = np.random.randint(2, size=(3, 25), dtype=bool)
>>> X
array([[False,  True, False, False, False, False,  True,  True,  True, True, False,  True,  True,  True,  True, False, False, False, True, False, False,  True,  True,  True, False],
       [False,  True,  True, False, False,  True,  True,  True,  True, False,  True, False, False,  True,  True, False,  True, False, True,  True,  True,  True, False, False,  True],
       [ True, False,  True,  True,  True, False,  True, False,  True, True, False,  True,  True, False, False, False, False,  True, False, False, False,  True, False, False,  True]])
```

If you want to pack the elements of this array, use [`numpy.packbits`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.packbits.html):

```
>>> Y = np.packbits(X, axis=1)
>>> Y
array([[ 67, 222,  39,   0],
       [103, 166, 188, 128],
       [186, 216,  68, 128]], dtype=uint8)
```

It could be observed that elements of boolean type are indeed not memory-efficient:

```
def inspect_array(arr): 
    print('Number of elements in the array:', arr.size)
    print('Length of one array element in bytes:', arr.itemsize)
    print('Total bytes consumed by the elements of the array:', arr.nbytes)

>>> inspect_array(X)
Number of elements in the array: 75
Length of one array element in bytes: 1
Total bytes consumed by the elements of the array: 75
>>> inspect_array(Y)
Number of elements in the array: 12
Length of one array element in bytes: 1
Total bytes consumed by the elements of the array: 12
```

You could also unpack bits using the following

```
Z = np.unpackbits(Y, axis=1).astype(bool)[:, :X.shape[1]]
```

and make sure this is right

```
>>> np.array_equal(X, Z)
True
```

It also looks the same problem [remains in pandas](https://vincentteyssier.medium.com/optimizing-the-size-of-a-pandas-dataframe-for-low-memory-environment-5f07db3d72e/). So you could make your dataframe into numpy array, pack/unpack bits and then make it back into dataframe.